# Is there a way to link main class references from the test class references in jxr?

Tags: maven

Using the maven jxr plugin, is there a way to produce the test report in such a way that main classes will be linked to the main class report?

Comment: Do you mean [maven-jxr-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/jxr/maven-jxr-plugin/)?